# The LinkAssemblies Task Failed Unexpectedly - Android.Support.V7.Internal.View.Menu.MenuBuilder

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've upgraded my app to the very latest Xamarin/Xamarin Android i have hit an issue when building with Sdk Assemblies Only in my Linker properties. This was not an issue with the previous version of Xamarin (3.11.1594. / 5.1.7.12) i was using.

I have also changed my app to use Android 6.0 (23) as the compile and Target version.

Error as follows:

```
Error The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'Android.Support.V7.Internal.View.Menu.MenuBuilder' (defined in 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Android.Support.V7.Internal.View.Menu.MenuBuilder
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() Droid
```

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: Have you updated the build tools and the sdk tools and the support libraries via the android sdk manager?

Comment: in SDK Manager i have Android Support Library 23.2.1, Build Tools 23.0.3 and Android SDK Tools 25.1.3 installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps fixed the issue:

I upgraded my Xamarin.Android.Support.Design NuGet package from 23.0.1.3 to 23.3.0 to match the other Xamarin.Android.Support.* package versions that were already installed in my project.

This stopped the Linker error above but another error was reported that the location and files did not exist at:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded

After investigating, i downloaded the repository from:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip

I then extracted the repository and opened the following file in winrar:
android_m2repository_r29\m2repository\com\android\support\design\23.3.0\design-23.3.0.aar

When the contents of that file were extracted into the new embedded folder above, the project built, deployed and published an apk with SDK Assemblies Only selected.